# Customizing TwoDArrayWritable in Hadoop and Not able to iterate the same in reducer

Tags: arrays, class, hadoop, mapreduce, writable

Trying to emit 2 double dimensional array as value from mapper.
In hadoop we have `TwoDArrayWritable` which takes 1 - `2D array` as input.
In order to achieve my usecase, I tried to edit `TwoDArrayWritable` to take input of `2` - `2D array`

```
/**
 * A Writable for 2D arrays containing a matrix of instances of a class.
 */
public class MyTwoDArrayWritable implements Writable {


    private Class valueClass;
    private Writable[][] values;


    private Class valueClass1;
    private Writable[][] values1;


    public MyTwoDArrayWritable(Class valueClass,Class valueClass1) {
        this.valueClass = valueClass;
        this.valueClass1 = valueClass1;
    }

    public MyTwoDArrayWritable(Class valueClass, DoubleWritable[][] values,Class valueClass1, DoubleWritable[][] values1) {
        this(valueClass, valueClass1);
        this.values = values;
        this.values1 = values1;
    }

    public Object toArray() {
        int dimensions[] = {values.length, 0};
        Object result = Array.newInstance(valueClass, dimensions);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            Object resultRow = Array.newInstance(valueClass, values[i].length);
            Array.set(result, i, resultRow);
            for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
                Array.set(resultRow, j, values[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }



    /**
     * @return the valueClass
     */
    public Class getValueClass() {
        return valueClass;
    }

    /**
     * @param valueClass the valueClass to set
     */
    public void setValueClass(Class valueClass) {
        this.valueClass = valueClass;
    }

    /**
     * @return the values
     */
    public Writable[][] getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    /**
     * @param values the values to set
     */
    public void setValues(DoubleWritable[][] values,DoubleWritable[][] values1) {
        this.values = values;
        this.values = values1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the valueClass1
     */
    public Class getValueClass1() {
        return valueClass1;
    }

    /**
     * @param valueClass1 the valueClass1 to set
     */
    public void setValueClass1(Class valueClass1) {
        this.valueClass1 = valueClass1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the values1
     */
    public Writable[][] getValues1() {
        return values1;
    }


    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        // construct matrix
        values = new Writable[in.readInt()][];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            values[i] = new Writable[in.readInt()];
        }

        // construct values
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
                Writable value;                             // construct value
                try {
                    value = (Writable) valueClass.newInstance();
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());
                }
                value.readFields(in);                       // read a value
                values[i][j] = value;                       // store it in values
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt(values.length);                 // write values
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            out.writeInt(values[i].length);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
                values[i][j].write(out);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

And emited 2 2D double array from mapper.

```
MyTwoDArrayWritable array = new MyTwoDArrayWritable (DoubleWritable.class,DoubleWritable.class);
DoubleWritable[][] myInnerArray = new DoubleWritable[EtransEkey.length][EtransEkey[0].length];
DoubleWritable[][] myInnerArray1 = new DoubleWritable[EtransDevalue.length][EtransDevalue[0].length];
// set values in myInnerArray
for (int k1 = 0; k1 < EtransEkey.length; k1++) {
 for(int j1=0;j1< EtransEkey[0].length;j1++){
     myInnerArray[k1][j1] = new DoubleWritable(EtransEkey[k1][j1]);

 }
}

for (int k1 = 0; k1 < EtransDevalue.length; k1++) {
 for(int j1=0;j1< EtransDevalue[0].length;j1++){
     myInnerArray1[k1][j1] = new DoubleWritable(EtransDevalue[k1][j1]);
 }
}

array.set(myInnerArray,myInnerArray1);
```

Showing error in `array.set(myInnerArray,myInnerArray1);`

```
/*
 * The method set(DoubleWritable[][], DoubleWritable[][]) is undefined for the type MyTwoDArrayWritableritable
 */
```

**EDIT:** How to iterate through these values in Reducer to get myInnerArray matrix and myInnerArray1 matrix?

So far what I did is

```
for (MyTwoDArrayWritable c : values) {
            System.out.println(c.getValues());
            DoubleWritable[][] myInnerArray = new DoubleWritable[KdimRow][KdimCol];
            for (int k1 = 0; k1 < KdimRow; k1++) {
                 for(int j1=0;j1< KdimCol;j1++){
                     myInnerArray[k1][j1] = new DoubleWritable();

                 }
        }
```

**But how to store them back to a double array?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not defined the `set` method in `MyTwoDArrayWritable`, that is why that error is shown. Instead of calling `array.set`, you should use the method you have already defined which does exactly what you need: `setValues`, so replace

```
array.set(myInnerArray,myInnerArray1);
```

with

```
array.setValues(myInnerArray,myInnerArray1);
```

Comment: oh right I was calling wrong method. How to traverse through this MyTwoDArrayWritable in Reducer inorder to get myInnerArray and myInnerArray1

Comment: You said you are using `MyTwoDArrayWritable` as values, right? So for each key in the reducer you should have a collection of `MyTwoDArrayWritable`. Iterate through them and build the matrix just as you are doing in the code you posted.

Comment: yes my values are MyTwoDArrayWritable. But how to make them back to double array? I am stuck.Please see my edit

Comment: My answer solves your initial problem, and you have created another thread to solve the second problem. Could you please accept the answer?